# Can I return any variable from WSL?

Tags: linux, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) because of the accuracy of the Linux timers. Therefore, I would like to return a variable which can trigger an output on my Windows machine. It can be thought as interrupt. According to Microsoft page, these two systems share resources (Environment variables, files, networks), however I have not found any information regarding my question. Is it possible to return any variable from Linux to host Windows OS via PowerShell?

Before I realized that I can use bash commands in PowerShell and thought I do not need to have communication between these 2 systems. However, when I used bash date function in PowerShell, I do not get the same accuracy which I get from Linux. I will be appreciated any suggestion.

Comment: You can run `wsl --help` from PowerShell to see the full options, but you should be able to do something like `wsl -d <distribution name> <options> <arguments>` i.e. `$Test = wsl -d Alpine ifconfig`. If you are talking about shared environment variables, see this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/). FYI, "bash commands in PowerShell", these are almost always aliases for PowerShell cmdlets and not the commands you think they are, so they definitely have different output.

Comment: [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.1) is highly customisable as far as time format goes. See the examples for `Format` and `UFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. As far as I understood that you are telling me that I runned a command which is basically in PowerShell. I think according to `wsl --help`  there is no returning variable from Linux. When I run `$Test = wsl -d Ubuntu ifconfig` , I do not get any output.

Comment: If you have run it in PowerShell and then run `$Test`  it should show you the content of the variable, if `ifconfig` still works as a command on Ubuntu, I can never remember across various distros))

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had to write Ubuntu and its version.

Comment: Yeah, some distros have version numbers in the name. You can check like this `wsl -l --verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

From Powershell you can invoke WSL and return the output of the Linux date utility.

```
PS> wsl.exe date +%m-%Y
07-2021
PS> $date = wsl.exe date +%Y%m%d
PS> $date
20210728
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am using the similar code :
`$time = wsl date +'%T.%3N'` 
The problem is that 5 ms pulse is needed in my app. I would like to get any command or returning variable after 5 ms from Linux to host Windows. I guess it is impossible in the current state-of-the-art.